# What does Ctrl+/ do in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, keyboard-layout

when I press **CTRL+/**, it seems to have the same outcome as the shortcut **CTRL+U**, which deletes before the cursor until the start of the command.

Does anyone know of **CTRL+/** in Linux?

Comment: Run the command `od -t x1z`, then press Ctrl+/, then press Ctrl+D. You should get a hexadecimal representation of the character(s) generated for the Ctrl-/ keystroke by your keyboard layout and terminal emulator configuration.

Comment: It's not necessarily the same outcome. In my Kubuntu, if I press Up to get a line from history and I append something, and I press Ctrl+/ then it will delete what I appended. Ctrl+u would delete everything.

Comment: Wow! bash have Undo! Try to edit your command and then press Ctrl+/. It works like Ctrl+Z in text editors.

Comment: @telcoM `od` isn't always a good tool to debug such issues, as it doesn't see the bytes handled by (or altered by) the kernel's tty driver. For example Ctrl+U removes the line rather than reporting its generated byte 21. Use `showkey -a` instead.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> seems to generate the same character code as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>_</kbd> (control underline). In Bash, this is the keybinding for undo.

The ASCII character generated is `US` (unit separator), whose code is 31 or hex 1F.

The reason it seems to have the same effect as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> is that you typed some input and it's just undoing that. Try typing some input, then backspacing over some of it and then using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>_</kbd>.

This is not a "Linux" behavior. In an actual Linux VGA console on an Intel machine, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> produces the DEL characters, 127. That character is often notated `^?`, so it makes sense that way.  Bash interprets it as a backspace.

Comment: It is a mistake to assume that all keyboard layouts and terminal emulators produce the same ASCII characters on that keystroke. For example, on this Mac with a Finnish keyboard layout, connected to a Debian 11 system over SSH, Ctrl-/ just causes the terminal emulator to beep without passing any input to the shell.

Comment: @telcoM  The DEC VT100 manual says that Ctrl plus the shifted or unshifted `?` key produces the `US` character.    If that doesn't happen, your terminal emulator not quite faithfully emulating a VT100. https://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html  (I'm not getting the right behavior when Shift is used.)

Comment: Even a Xterm is not 100% faithful to a DEC VT100, so unless the question was about retrocomputing, you are stating a vacuous truth. Also, you're assuming a US English keyboard layout.

Comment: @telcoM I tried it in Slovak and Japanese. Same result. Now various keys are mapped quite differently; for instance Y and Z are exchanged in the Slovak layout. (And so are Ctrl-Z and Ctr-Y!)   Firstly, does the unmodified / key produce a slash in your Finnish layout? In Slovak mode, / produces a hyphen -. Yet Ctrl-/ is still ASCII US. It's not obvious what Ctrl-/ has to do, or should have to do with language.

Comment: @telcoM I just tried it in actual Linux (i.e. Linux console on x86). It produces the DEL character.

Comment: And on my Finnish keyboard layout on x86 Linux console, "Ctrl-/" (which is actually Ctrl-Shift-7) simply produces the character "7". Pressing the key that on US English keyboard would produce "/" (and "?" with Shift) produces "-" and underline respectively, and pressing it together with Ctrl produces a Ctrl-underline character irrespective of shift state. Yes, the keyboard layouts are a hot steaming mess; hence my first comment.

Comment: @telcoM I find it extremely unlikely that any terminal emulator on any keystoke would decide to beep on its own and not emit any bytes. I'm almost certain that Ctrl-/ sends some bytes, to which in turn your shell responds by emitting the BEL character, i.e. asking the terminal to beep. Launch a `cat` and press this key there, see what happens.

Comment: @egmont I did essentially just that (actually I launched `od -x1` to view a hex representation of the bytes). **No characters were emitted** by that keystroke by the macOS terminal, neither over the SSH connection to a Linux `bash` session nor locally on macOS's own `zsh`-based session. It was a sad surprise to me too. I think the beep was effectively an error: "No characters mapped to that keystroke."

Comment: @telcoM I just filed another comment (to the original question) explaining that `od` is the wrong tool.

Comment: And sure, me suggesting here to use `cat` wasn't a good idea either.

Comment: @egmont Same results on `showkey -a` also. It displays the Ctrl-D used to terminate `showkey -a` but nothing at all for the Ctrl-Shift-7 (which is Ctrl-/ on my Finnish keyboard). On the other hand, both Ctrl-minus and Ctrl-underline will produce 0x1f.

Comment: @telcoM Well, if it produces nothing then probably indeed nothing is generated by the terminal. Still, it's weird to me why your terminal emulator would decide to beep instead of staying silent, it's a pattern I haven't seen anywhere. Just for curiosity, to double check: what happens if you redirect the output to a file, does it still beep immediately, rather than a BEL character appearing in the file?

Comment: @egmont Same result: immediate beep and a zero-length file after I press Ctrl-D to terminate the redirection. I assume we are both in agreement about macOS terminal being weird.

Comment: @telcoM Agree :) I'm honestly surprised. Thanks for your help in solving this mystery! :)

Answer (score 0):

The bash/readline emacs-style keybinding list is poorly documented,however the source shows that there is no readline/bash keybinding specifically for C-/.

Instead the scancodes for various keyboards are mapped to keycodes which are in turn mapped to a characters.   The utility 'showkey' shows this clearly.
On my US keyboard both for C-/ to the same character as C-*.  So bash has one binding for C-* (to undo) and has no ability to distinguish the differnet keyscans that generate this same character.

https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html

man 1 showkey